# How to find the sample size for a voting poll with a given spread?

Tags: statistics, sampling

I do not know what to do with the following exercise:

> A polling company asks $n$ random people which party they will vote for in the next election. How big does $n$ need to be so that the spread for each party  in a $95\% -$confidence interval is $\pm 1\%$?
>
> Remark: We assume that there are $> 2$ parties

My problems with this exercise start with that I do not understand what we are estimating here. (I mean I get that we try to predict the outcome of an election, but I can not relate this to a concept from stochastics like say expected value or something.)

The only thing somehow related to this from my lecture ist that if $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $\sigma^2$ is known we can compute a lower bound for the sample size by the equation

$$n_{min} = \frac{u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}^2 \sigma^2}{b^2},$$ where $b$ is the width of the confidence interval of level $1-\alpha$.

However, I do not see why we can assume that the population is normally distributed here or why we should know $\sigma^2$, so this probably does not work here.

Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: I have no idea what the "spread for each party" might mean.   I assume (though it is not certain) that we are to imagine that each person will vote for $A$ with probability $p$ and for $B$ with probability $1-p$, independent of all other voters.  Thus the distribution is binomial, though you might use a normal approximation if conditions are suitable.

Comment: @lulu: Thanks for your answer. With "spread" I mean "fluctuation range", sorry for the confusion, but English is not my native language. To make it clear: Immediately after the vote preliminary results with an accuracy of  say $\pm 3\%$ are published, so each party might have $3\%$ more or less in the final result. This is what I mean.

Comment: @lulu: Furhtermore, we only have a binomial distribution if there are only two parties. But what can we do if we have  say six parties like in Germany? This is what I do not understand.

Comment: So...using the notation of my first comment, you want to determine $p$ and $1-p$ within $.01$  with  $95\%$ confidence?

Comment: I have no idea how many parties your problem contemplates.  Clearly that parameter matters.  For each party $i$, you can still approach it as a binomial problem, just let $p_i$ be the probability of voting for $i$, so $1-p_i$ is the probability of voting for someone else.

Comment: Yes, I want to determine $p$ and $1-p$ within $0.01$ with $95\%$ confidence and  unfortunately the problem is not clear on how many parties are involved, so I suppose I need to find a general approach.

Comment: So, allowing for $k$ parties, solve each of the $k$ binomial problems.  Take the greatest of the various $n$.  Clearly, if you have lots of parties, you'll need a big sample.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help thus far, I will have to think about this for a bit now.

Comment: Err, the actual number of parties doesn’t matter since for each one it’s effectively a single binomial problem with that party either being chosen or it being anyone else.